# How do I set a value as an Icon?

Tags: c#, string, text, icons, minesweeper

I have a problem. First I'll show you a small code excerpt from my Minesweeper game I'm making.

```
lbl_grid[mineX, mineY].Text = "*";
```

Now, what this does is it sets a mine in my grid to look like a `*`.

What I want instead is for `lbl_grid[mineX, mineY].Text` to be assigned a value of an Icon. Is this possible?

I believe I may have to use something other than text, since icons aren't text.

Comment: It sounds like basically you shouldn't be using `Label` (as they're designed to show text)... consider using `PictureBox` instead.

Comment: what gui are you using? windows forms? then you can use `PictureBox.Image`.

Comment: you should use the Image control and set the Image property instead

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you will have to use something other than text.

An option is to make a 2D array of PictureBox.

```
int rows = 3;
int cols = 4;

List<List<PictureBox>> pictures = new List<List<PictureBox>>();

for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    List<PictureBox> pList = new List<PictureBox>();
    for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    {
        //do any positioning you need to do here
        pList.Add(new PictureBox());
    }
    pictures.Add(pList);
}
```

Then you can access and set the Image Source.

```
pictures[rVal][cVal].Image = Image.FromFile("<file path>");
```

Comment: As you said, an option is to make a 2D array of PictureBox, but that's not a 2D array of PictureBox. `PictureBox[,] pictures = new PictureBox[rows,cols]();` is a 2D array.

Comment: And by 2d array I mean List of List. I'm a list guy.